# NSPipe - How to convert returned data to NSArray

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, nstask

My application uses NSTask to start a Python script, then the script returns an array via NSPipe. I read the data, stick it in a string, and display it:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSData *readData;

while ((readData = [readHandle availableData])&& [readData length]) {
    [data appendData: readData];
}


NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] 
                    initWithData: data 
                    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

That's all fine, but I realized I really need to keep it as an array - not a string. I can't find a method that initiates array from data (data returned from NSPipe). How can I do that? The closest thing I found is possibly using:

`[NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:]`

... but I don't need a "property list" per se. Do I have to convert the data to plist first?

**EDITED:** I just realized it's more complicated than I thought. Python returns an array of dictionaries, in the dictionary there are strings. These strings can have commas and other chars, so I don't think I can use a "," separator to break it up.

in Python:

```
msg_set = []
msg_set = [
   dict(mts="t,s1", mfrom="f@ro,m1", msbj="msb,j1", mbody="bod,y1", mid="i,d1"),
   dict(mts="ts2", mfrom="from2", msbj="msb,j2", mbody="body2", mid="id2")
]
print msg_set # <- this is what python returns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the data to JSON first (I saw the comments on dasblinkenlight's answer but I  had already typed my answer) and then pass them to Cocoa. Something like this:

**Python Side**

```
import json
#...
json.dumps(msg_set) # <- return this one instead
```

**Objective-C Side**

```
NSString *myPythonJson = @""; // <- Whatever you got from python
NSError *error = nil;
id myObjectsFromJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myPythonJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data coming back represents an array with a separator, e.g. a comma `@","` you can take your string, and split it into an array, like this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] 
                initWithData: data 
                encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

You need to use the same separator character as the sending side. If multiple characters can be used as separators, you may want to use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` instead:

```
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my question. The returned array might contain strings with "," in them, so I don't think I can use a componentsSeparatedByString:@",".   (it breaks "bod,y" into "y")

Comment: @janeh You need a parser for something as complex as this. Do you control the Python side? Can you change its output to be more parse-friendly, e.g. [encode its results as JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)?

Comment: The strings are coming to python from IMAP, but I can control how they are "grouped" before sending them to obj-c. I thought an array of dics would be the best, but guess not. I have never used JSON before, but let me see what I can do...